# Changing a string from a file to an integer

Tags: python

I have created code that asks the user some questions. They input their name and a class, this information is then stored onto a csv file. I have then created a new documents that displays the scores and name although the score I want to be stored next to the name in highest to lowest. The program I would also like to only display the last three scores for each user.

This is the code I have at the moment:

```
import csv 

all_students = []
all_scores = [] 
file = (open('ELZ.csv'))
every_test = csv.reader(file)
for row in every_test:
    if all_students.count(row[0]) == 0:
        all_students.append(row[0])
        all_scores.append(row)
else:
    pos = all_students.index(row[0])
    score = all_scores[pos]
    score.append(row[1])
    if len(score) > 4:
        del(score[1])
        all_scores[pos] = score

summery = []
for i in range(0, len(all_students)):
    student_row = [None] * 3
    input_row=all_scores[i]
for j in range(1,len(input_row)):
    input_row[j] = (int(input_row[j]))
student_row[0] = input_row.pop(0)
student_row[1] = (max(input_row))
student_row[2] = (sum(input_row))
print(student_row)
summery.append(student_row)
print(summery)
from operator import itemgetter
print(sorted(summery, key=itemgetter(0)))
print(sorted(summery, key=itemgetter(1)))
print(sorted(summery, key=itemgetter(2)))
```

`

this is the error message I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\charlotte lily\Documents\python\python unicorns.py", line 62, in <module>
input_row[j] = (int(input_row[j]))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:
```

Comment: In its current form of the code, it will never reach the line you are referring to, so it's hard to identify your real problem.

Comment: I think you've lost indentation when posting the code here.

Comment: Do a `print(input_row[j])` before the line that throws the exception to see what you're trying to convert to an integer. @VolodymyrKirichinets: The brackets are relevant - this creates the list `[None, None, None]`.

Comment: You can try (int(input_row[j])) change as (str(input_row[j])), and then if traceback give some str error back str to int.